# What is the english description for this DFA?

Tags: finite-automata

Practicing some DFAs and NFAs and came across this one. Not sure how to give an English description let alone a regular expression.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be "even number of both 0's and 1's".  Top right state is "odd # of 0's", bottom left is "odd # of 1's", bottom right is "both odd".

Comment: Can you give me a description that i could convert to regular expressions?

Comment: I'm not sure it's even possible to translate this to a traditional regular expression; the only way I can think of making a regex that does this job would require a lookahead assertion, which I think makes the language not regular (in the CompSci sense).